# What does "Construct a bijection" mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What does it mean to construct a bijection between two sets for exmaple?
I know what a injective, surjective and bijective function is, but what about does it mean to construct a bijection?

Comment: To give an explicit (injective and surjective) relation between the elements of the two sets.

Comment: It's to *define* a bijective function from one set to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you make a **prescription**.

E.g. $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ **prescribed by**: $x\mapsto -x+7$

Answer (score 0):

You want to construct a map that is both injective and surjective from one of the sets into the other. Here is an example:

Define

$X = \{a,b,c\}$

$Y = \{1,2,3\}$

I can construct the bijection sending $a$ to $1$, $b$ to $2$ and $c$ to $3$. You may check that this is a bijection. Your bijection could be many different things, and depends on the sets you're playing with.